# Grid as bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

A common layout in many sites is to draw the grid as shaded bars:

[image]

I'm doing this with this function:

```
grid_bars <- function(data, y, n = 5, fill = "gray90") {
  breaks <- pretty(data[[y]], n)
  len <- length(breaks)-1
  all_bars <- data.frame(
    b.id = rep(1:len, 4),
    b.x = c(rep(-Inf, len), rep(Inf, len*2), rep(-Inf, len)),
    b.y = c(rep(breaks[-length(breaks)], 2), rep(breaks[-1], 2))
  )
  bars <- all_bars[all_bars$b.id %in% (1:len)[c(FALSE, TRUE)], ]
  grid <- list(
    geom_polygon(data = bars, aes(b.x, b.y, group = b.id),
                 fill = fill, colour = fill),
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks),
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
  )
  return(grid)
}

#-------------------------------------------------

dat <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972,
                  level = as.vector(LakeHuron))

ggplot(dat, aes(year, level)) +
  grid_bars(dat, "level", 10) +
  geom_line(colour = "steelblue", size = 1.2) +
  theme_classic()
```

But it needs to specify *data* and *y* again. How to take those directly from the ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a look at the options for extending [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) in Hadley Wickham's [book](https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html) on ggplot2 you probably have to set up your own `Geom` or `Stat` layer to achieve the desired result. This way you can access the data and aesthetics specified in `ggplot()` or even pass different data and aesthetics to your fun. Still a newbie in writing extensions for `ggplot2` but a first approach may look like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Make bars dataframe
make_bars_df <- function(y, n) {
  breaks <- pretty(y, n)
  len <- length(breaks) - 1
  all_bars <- data.frame(
    group = rep(1:len, 4),
    x = c(rep(-Inf, len), rep(Inf, len * 2), rep(-Inf, len)),
    y = c(rep(breaks[-length(breaks)], 2), rep(breaks[-1], 2))
  )
  all_bars[all_bars$group %in% (1:len)[c(FALSE, TRUE)], ]
}

# Setup Geom
geom_grid_bars_y <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                           position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                           inherit.aes = TRUE, n = 5, ...) {
  layer(
    geom = GeomGridBarsY, mapping = mapping,  data = data, stat = stat,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(n = n, ...)
  )
}

GeomGridBarsY <- ggproto("GeomGridBarsY", Geom,
                        required_aes = c("y"),
                        default_aes = aes(alpha = NA, colour = NA, fill = "gray90", group = NA,
                                          linetype = "solid", size = 0.5, subgroup = NA),
                        non_missing_aes = aes("n"),
                        setup_data = function(data, params) {
                          transform(data)
                        },

                        draw_group = function(data, panel_scales, coord, n = n) {
                          bars <- make_bars_df(data[["y"]], n)
                          # setup data for GeomPolygon
                          ## If you want this to work with facets you have to take care of the PANEL
                          bars$PANEL <- factor(1)
                          # Drop x, y, group from data
                          d <- data[ , setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y", "group"))] 
                          d <- d[!duplicated(d), ]
                          # Merge information in data to  bars
                          bars <- merge(bars, d, by = "PANEL")
                          # Set color = fill
                          bars[["colour"]] <- bars[["fill"]] 
                          # Draw
                          grid::gList(
                            ggplot2::GeomPolygon$draw_panel(bars, panel_scales, coord)
                          )
                        },

                        draw_key = draw_key_rect
)

grid_bars <- function(n = 5, fill = "gray90") {
  list(
    geom_grid_bars_y(n = n, fill = fill),
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = n)),
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
  )
}

dat <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972,
                  level = as.vector(LakeHuron))

ggplot(dat, aes(year, level)) +
  grid_bars(n = 10, fill = "gray95") +
  geom_line(colour = "steelblue", size = 1.2) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**Just for reference**:

A first and simple approach to get grid bars one could simply adjust the size of the grid lines via `theme()` like so:

```r
# Simple approach via theme
ggplot(dat, aes(year, level)) +
  geom_line(colour = "steelblue", size = 1.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 8))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I initially thought about manipulating the grid but couldn't find a way to either alternate them or make them proportional to the break interval.